# Need to add Share button in this library android frames

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio, android-library, android-glide

Currently developing an android app using below library

[enter link description here][1]https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/Frames/blob/master/library/src/main/java/jahirfiquitiva/libs/frames/activities/base/BaseWallpaperViewerActivity.java

[1]want to add share button in this code can any tell me logic using this code how can i do that.
Want to replace icon info button with share button

```
private void saveWallpaperAction(final Context context) {
    if (downloadDialog != null) {
        downloadDialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onSaveAction();
    }

    final boolean[] enteredDownloadTask = {false};

    downloadDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
            .content(R.string.downloading_wallpaper)
            .progress(true, 0)
            .cancelable(false)
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction
                        which) {
                    if (downloadDialog != null) {
                        downloadDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            })
            .show();

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(item.getURL())
            .asBitmap()
            .dontAnimate()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap>
                        glideAnimation) {
                    if (resource != null && downloadDialog.isShowing()) {
                        enteredDownloadTask[0] = true;
                        try {
                            saveWallpaper(((Activity) context), item.getName(),
                                    downloadDialog, resource);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Do nothing
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUIThread(context, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!enteredDownloadTask[0]) {
                        String newContent = context.getString(R.string.downloading_wallpaper)
                                + "\n"
                                + context.getString(R.string.download_takes_longer);
                        downloadDialog.setContent(newContent);
                        downloadDialog.setActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE, android.R
                                .string.cancel);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: can any one help me on this? i am stuck how to share on this page.